# Intellij - How to find which methods in class A are in the call tree of a method in class B

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a class, `B`, which has method `foo()`. I want to be able to answer: when `B.foo()` is called, which methods in another class `A` are in the call hierarchy?

`A` is a much, much lower-level class, so using IntelliJ's built-in [call hierarchy](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/guide/tips/call-hierarchy/) hasn't worked for me - I can't manually browse the call tree so far down so many branches. Ideally, I'd like to filter the call tree to only branches which end with `A.<something>()`, to be able to say "when `B.foo()` is called, it might eventually call `A.bar1()` and `A.bar3()`, but not `A.bar2()`. Is there a built-in way to get this info?

Comment: Hello, there is no ready tool to make such a filtering. Please feel free to create an issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Thank you